# Storing only values in an ini files

Tags: c#, ini

I know .ini are not popular in the .net world. I apologize in advance in my attempt to use them.

I have an ini file that stores all app settings in a typical key value pair manner. Now I want to add to it , the contents of a few richtextboxes . The richtextbox holds paths to folders in each line. The thing is I want there to be no key ,but only values in the ini file. Something like this:

```
[Folders]
c:/
d:/
e:/my downloads
```

Basically want to know how to store only values in an ini file ( no keys). Not sure if this can or should be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply give them keys in the form of Folder1, Folder2, FolderN?
It depends on your implementation. You could simply iterate over all available keys in the section and retrive the values.

Comment: +1 because I always see this strategy applied, in the registry too: teh Visual Studio MRU list for example.

Comment: Or just 0=, 1= 2=, you can simply loop until the next number is not found OR include a count=

Comment: why am I not intelligent enough to think of these solutions myself . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This can done using [Cinchoo framework](http://www.cinchoo.com).

For a sample (C:\Temp\Test.Ini) ini file below,

```
[Folders]
c:/
d:/
e:/my downloads
```

Using Cinchoo framework, you can iterate through them as below

```
using (ChoIniDocument doc = ChoIniDocument.Load(@"C:\Temp\Test.Ini"))
{
    foreach (string key in doc.GetSection("Folders").Keys)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(key);
    }
}
```